# Laravel return text/html and not json?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this in response headers:

```
Response headers (165 B)    
    Host    
    "localhost:8000"
    [Learn More]
    Connection  
    "close"
    [Learn More]
    Content-Type    
    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    [Learn More]
    Date    
    "Thu, 16 Mar 2017 14:33:53 GMT"
    [Learn More]
    Transfer-Encoding   
    "chunked"
```

My  controller is quite simple:

```
public function login(Request $request){

      return response()->json([
        'name' => 'Abigail',
        'state' => 'CA'
        ]);
    }
```

Im using angular for post.

Comment: What is the current response?

Comment: <br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
{"name":"Abigail","state":"CA"}

Comment: it returns me like this.. i dont know if its wrong because of angular post or ?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea, I think you can better try to debug with postman first or look in your chrome dev console to see the output generated by laravel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Laravel provides modify header information using **Response** class.

Try this way in your controller :

```
$contents = View::make('embedded')->with('foo', $foo);
$response = Response::make($contents, $statusCode);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
return $response;
```

Comment: Note that you might have to use `\Response` and `\View` (or `use Response; use View;`) unless you use these classes manually, when working in a namespace.

Comment: Important: You need to use 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;' not  'Illuminate\Http\Response;'

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;` and `use Response;`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found a simple solution...
This is:

```
return response($html, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
```